# Request for Assistance: Implementing Linkedin Field Autofill in WP Job Manager Plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, linkedin-api

my name is Ismael.

I have a project in which I need help to implement a field autofill with Linkedin on a form.

The application will have the WP Job Manager plugin and what I need is that when a candidate registers or applies for a job, the option to fill in through Linkedin appears.

Thank you!

I haven't tried anything because I'm not sure how to do it. What I hope is that when a candidate wants to apply for a job position, they have the option to automatically fill in their candidate data through their LinkedIn profile.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.